# Display meta info in console after failed test in TestCafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

When a test in TestCafe is failing I will get the normal error message together with the location of the error. I will also get the fixture name and the test name.

But, when running a large number of tests in a CI environment, it can be cumbersome to locate the test.

I wish to display the test's meta info in the console on failure. Can this be done in TestCafe?

Answer (score 2):

Test's meta is passed to reporters. Built-in reporters however don't display `meta` information on test failure. You can look for an appropriate reporter in [npm](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/extend-testcafe/reporter-plugin.html#implement-the-reporter) or implement a custom reporter that will display `meta` information on test failure (see more detail [here](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/extend-testcafe/reporter-plugin.html#implement-the-reporter)).